# How do i put my head around ISAPI Filters

Tags: c++, iis

I am a newbie. I have decent command over C++ but i lack domain knowledge when it comes to servers and stuff. My current assignment is to write ISAPI filters for IIS Web Server. I have been googling for a couple of days and have found out that its quite a challenging task. I found some examples [here](http://www.genusa.com/isapi/isapisrc.html). I need to understand and implement some filters which would log requests to the server and take a count of requests on each resource. I do not seem to understand the code examples. Can you guys please suggest a plan or list of to do's for me. I ask this because i know there are a lot of prerequisites to this project. Where should I start ? How should I proceed ? I am expecting you guys to look at the code examples [here](http://www.genusa.com/isapi/isapisrc.html) and tell me what stuff I should read up to grasp the examples. Then i could imagine writing my own filters.

Comment: we're expecting you to do your own research, then actually try something before coming here for help ;-) ISAPI filters are not difficult - it's just a C++ class that is invoked on each request that can alter the request and/or have some side-effect. Been around since the mid-1990s. Not rocket surgery.

Comment: Those code examples are rather old and I'd be careful of what version of IIS are you writing and what version is what you are using as a reference as I'd imagine an ISAPI filter that worked in IIS 3.0 may not work in IIS 7.0 for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a great tutorial on the MSDN magazine website

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301704.aspx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2002/august/asp-net-intercept-monitor-and-modify-web-requests-with-http-filters-in-isapi-and-asp-net)

You should be able to follow through the above article and then read through the further reading down the bottom and it should help you to userstand what ISAPI filters are and how they work.

**Edit**: looks like the further reading is defunct (thanks microsoft).  So I've done a little more research and found 2 more article with code examles.  One of which is actually logging usernames from request cookies (code project).

Excerpt.

> If you've reached this point, chances are you want the general
> solution, one that maps any arbitrary URL to your implementation ASP
> or ASPX files without the limitation of the file extension I've
> discussed. The only way I know to do this is outside the .NET
> Framework, using plain old ISAPI filters. You see, ISAPI filters are
> HTTP handlers native to IIS and they are given a chance to run very
> early, before any framework code in ASP.NET.
> Conceptually, ISAPI filters are very similar to the ASP.NET
> HTTPModules I discussed earlier. A major difference is that ISAPI
> filters must be written in C or C++. There is plenty of literature on
> ISAPI filters so I will only touch on them briefly here (see ISAPI,
> and Tips and Tricks for ISAPI Programming for more information).
> In practice, an ISAPI filter is a Windows DLL that provides the
> following two entry points:

```
DWORD WINAPI HttpFilterProc(   
  PHTTP_FILTER_CONTEXT pfc,   
  DWORD notificationType,   LPVOID pvNotification 
);

BOOL WINAPI GetFilterVersion(
   PHTTP_FILTER_VERSION pVer 
);
```

> The IIS runtime calls the GetFilterVersion method when the filter is
> initialized. The filter should use this opportunity to notify IIS
> about the events it cares about. Then, when HTTP requests arrive, IIS
> calls the HttpFilterProc once for every event for which the filter
> asked to be notified. If you want to make things a little bit easier
> you can use the MFC class CHttpFilter, which conveniently wraps the
> raw C API and routes the events to one or more virtual methods that
> you implement. The rest of the discussion will assume that you use the
> MFC-provided wrapper (see Writing Interactive Web Apps is a Piece of
> Cake with the New ISAPI Classes in MFC 4.1).
> Figure 6 shows the C++ code that rewrites the URL and stores
> part of the virtual path in a pseudoheader. The event that you need to
> catch in order to rewrite the URL is OnPreprocHeaders. The trick here
> is that you can use the special header URL to read the original URL.
> Then, after rewriting the URL, you can use the SetHeader call to set
> the special header URL, forcing IIS to call your file. The code shown
> in Figure 6 changes a URL like /bestpayroll/msdnmag/ report2 to
> /bestpayroll/report2.aspx. Notice how the company name has been
> removed and the .aspx suffix has been added. Most of the ugly code
> deals with extracting the company name and then piecing together the
> rest of the URL for the request.
> The last remaining task is to communicate either the original
> URL or the company name to the ASP.NET form. There is no clean way to
> communicate from an ISAPI filter to either ASP or ASP.NET. What I can
> do is add a new header. A header called companyname can be read from
> ASP.NET using the Request.ServerVariables collections, as shown here:

```
<form id="test" method="post" runat="server">
     The company is
     <b><%=Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_COMPANYNAME"]%></b> </form>
```

> Here I hardcoded the logic that rewrites URLs into the C++ code. In
> more realistic scenarios the logic should reside in a configuration
> file that is parsed by the filter during initialization.

Perhaps better code examples of ISAPI Filters with a clearer explanation

- [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/03/01/writing-a-simple-isapi-filter.aspx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rakkimk/writing-a-simple-isapi-filter)
- [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/isapilogger.aspx](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3378/Username-logging-for-ASP-NET-ASP-using-an-ISAPI-Fi)

Answer (score 1):

All of the books on this subject are obsolete, and dirt cheap used on Amazon. [One](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1874416664). [Two](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1576101517). Shipping will be the main cost for you.